# что значит while read oldrev newrev ref?

Tags: bash

пробую выполнить [файл с кодом](https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa#file-post-receive)

```
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    echo "Ref $ref received."
done
```

после выполнения ввожу в консоль "любое значение" и ожидаю увидеть в ответе:

> Ref любое значение received.

но там

> Ref  received.

То есть значение пустое.

Так ли оно должно работать, как я ожидаю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вопрос относится не к программе *git*, а к программе *bash* (как следует из содержимого файла по приведённой ссылке), являющейся одной из реализаций posix-совместимой оболочки.

[согласно стандарту posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html), программа или встроенная в оболочку команда `read` должна прочитать одну строку из стандартного ввода, разбить её на слова, руководствуясь символами-разделителями из переменной окружения `IFS` ([по умолчанию](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03) — `<space><tab><newline>`), и присвоить их последовательно переменным окружения, имена которых переданы этой команде/программе в качестве аргументов.

---

в вашем случае на стандартный ввод команде/программе `read` передаётся строка, состоящая из двух слов — `любое значение`, а аргументов ей передаётся три — `oldrev newrev ref`.

соответственно, первое слово (`любое`) присваивается переменной окружения `oldrev`, второе слово (`значение`) присваивается переменной `newrev`, а переменной `ref` ничего не присваивается — недостаточно слов было передано.

---

`while список1; do список2; done` — это [составная команда](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04) для организации цикла: сначала выполняется набор команд `список1`, если он завершился с ненулевым кодом возврата, то выполнение всей составной команды прекращается, иначе выполняется набор `список2` и снова повторяется цикл с начала.

Comment: спасибо, тег заменил